# At 480px or less, change image and when clicked on revert back to the old image

Tags: jquery

I'm totally new to JQuery and still learning so i need some help with this one. I have a webpage with a banner on it and when the screensize is 480px or less it will replace the banner with a temporary image to make it faster for mobile users. So fas so good. But now to the problem. When users click on this temporary image it should revert back to the old image. In this case, the banner. How can i accomplish this?

My code so far:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() <= 480) {
            $("#img").attr("src", "temp_image.jpg");
    }
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="banner">
     <a href="#"><img id="img" src="banner.jpg" alt="banner" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do exactly what you asked you could just attach a click handler to the img and then have it replace the image the same way you are doing on document load. E.G

```
$('#img').click(function(){
    $("#img").attr("src", "banner.jpg");
    //following line to unbind the click handler so it doesnt keep firing (even though it wont do anything)
    $('#img').unbind();
});
```

However I think that Sergios answer is better for what you want.

One thing to keep in mind. You say it will 'make it faster for mobile users' but at this point the banner image has already loaded and you are just replacing it with another, surely this is actually going to make it slower as you are loading two images instead of one. In terms of looks it will look better but I don't think it will make it faster. If I've got the wrong end of the stick though please correct me!

Comment: Ahh, Sergios answer disappeared. Maybe it didn't work? :P I should point out that this probably isn't the best solution, but it should do what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks! That worked brilliant! Well, the idea was that when a mobile user visit the site, a less graphic image will appear that will load faster and if they want to see the banner or whatever they can click on it and the banner will appear.

Comment: Fair enough, if you like my answer or any others please remember to upvote them and accept the one that you found to be the most useful! Us people on StackOverfow are ego driven creatures...

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I think just removing the " from around document in your doc ready statement will make your code work - in order to revert the image you can use something along the lines of

```
$(document).on('click','#img',function() {
    if( $(this).attr('src') === 'temp.jpg' ) 
    {
         $(this).attr('src','mainimg.jpg')
    }
});
```

however i'm not sure if you want to also revert it back to the smaller image if the img element is clicked away from?

Comment: To change image at 480px works just fine. I just want to know how to make so that when the user click on the temp image it will revert back to the banner.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't fully understand your problem, i've edited my answer with something that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html a little to:

```
<div id="banner">
     <a href="#"><img id="img" src="banner.jpg" alt="banner" data-big="banner.jpg" data-small="test_image.jpg"/></a>
</div>
```

And result js might be kind of following (just to avoid hard-coded links):

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    if ( $(window).width() <= 480) {
            $("#img").attr("src", $("#img").data("small"));
    }

    $("#img").on("click", function () {
        var img = $("#img");
        if (img.attr("src") != img.data('big') {
            img.attr("src") = img.data('big');
        }
    });
});
```

Reverting image src back to little size depends on how you would like to handle it, have no idea for now :)